# Extracting numbers in scheme

Tags: numbers, scheme, extract

I'm looking for help for a question involving scheme.

I'm trying to extract numbers in scheme in a way that produces the numbers backwards relative to n

(extract-number n k)

For example, (extract-number 4321 0) should produce 1 and (extract-number 4321 1) should produce 2.
Also, n can be any length, and k can be assumed to be smaller than the length

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input number is a non-negative value in base 10 and that the index is valid, the trick is to "traverse" the number by taking successive quotients until we either find the expected index or run out of digits. Try this:

```
(define (extract-number n k)
  (cond ((zero? k) (modulo n 10))
        ((<= n 0)  (error "Invalid input"))
        (else      (extract-number (quotient n 10) (sub1 k)))))
```

For example:

```
(extract-number 4321 0)
=> 1

(extract-number 4321 1)
=> 2

(extract-number 10 3)
=> Invalid input
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it by changing the number to a string and making a substring using the pos parameter:

```
(define (extractNum num pos) 
    (string->number (substring (number->string num)
        (- (string-length (number->string num)) (+ 1 pos))
        (- (string-length (number->string num)) pos))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
; last-digit : number -> digit
;   return the last digit of n
;   Example: (last-digit 123) is 3
(define (last-digit n)
  (remainder n 10))

; remove-last-digit : number -> number
;   Example: (remove-last-digit 123) is 12
(define (remove-last-digit n)
  (quotient n 10))

; digits : number -> list-of-digits
;   return the digits of n 
;   Example: (digits 123) is (list 3 2 1)
(define (digits n)
  (if (<= 0 n 9)
      (list n)
      (cons (last-digit n)
            (digits (remove-last-digit n)))))

(define (extract-number n k)
  (list-ref (digits n) k))
```

An alternative way of defining `number->digits`.:

```
(define (number->digits n)
  (reverse (string->list (number->string n))))
```